# Is every element of a finite abelian group contained in a cyclic factor?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Suppose $A$ is a non-cyclic finite abelian group and $a\in A$. Can we always find $A_1,A_2\leq A$ such that $a\in A_1$ and $A=A_1\oplus A_2$?

Equivalently, is it true that given a finite abelian $A$ and an $a\in A$, we can decompose $A$ into cyclic factors, one of which contains $a$?

Comment: Why the downvotes? I was honestly thinking about this for a while and couldn't find counterexamples spelled out anywhere.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): you should show your attempts, thoughts, or any kind of "context".

Comment: @AnneBauval: I answered the question, at the same time I asked it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not true. Consider $A=C_8\times C_2$ and $a=(2,1)$.

Then $a$ generates a cyclic subgroup of order $4$. It is not itself a direct factor, because then the other factor would be of order $4$, so the total exponent would be $4$. On the other hand, the cycle generated by $a$ is a maximal cyclic subgroup of $A$ (it suffices to check that $a$ is not a square). Thus, $a$ is not contained in any cyclic factor of $A$.